# Handle signal from a widget whose reference is unkown

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

say I have implement a widget A, and it need to handle signal sent by widget C. However widget a doesn't have the reference of widget C(at lease very cumbersome to get). What's the proper way to do?

Here is a naive example:

```
class WidgetA(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self._tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.layout().addWidget(_tab_widget)
        self._tab_widget.addTab(WidgetB())
        self._tab_widget.addTab(...)

    def show_another_tab(self, index):
        self._tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(index)

class WidgetB(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.layout().addWidget(WidgetC())

class WidgetC(QtGui.QWidget):
    show_another_tab = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("show_another_tab")
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_another_tab.emit(2))
```

So basically, I have a more than one tab. There is a little button in one of the tabs. When user clicked the button I want to switch to another tab. Sadly the button is a child of a child .. of the WidgetA, so it's cumbersome for me to keep a reference of the button in WidgetA. More over the button may be dynamically created at runtime.

What's the proper way to use signal in this situation? Or should I just the reference of WidgetA in a global variable(I really don't want to do this, but is seems to be the simplest way)?

Comment: Connect a signal from widget c to a signal of widget b, and connect that signal to a slot of widget a?

Comment: @thuga I don't know if it's a good idea, if I got another widget d which is a child of widget c, and widget a want't to handle a signal from d.

Comment: Then you can either redesign your application so you won't have a problem like this, or you can just connect a signal from widget d to a signal of widget c.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a reference needn't be cumbersome if you are consistent about setting parents. If you did that in your example, you could do:

```
class WidgetA(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self._tab_widget.addTab(WidgetB(self))

    def show_another_tab(self, index):
        self._tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(index)

class WidgetB(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.layout().addWidget(WidgetC(self))

class WidgetC(QtGui.QWidget):
    show_another_tab = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.parent().parent().show_another_tab.emit(2))
```

But if you want to avoid long chains of `parent()` calls, a more global approach might be better. One way to do that is to set `qApp` to a subclass of `QApplication`:

```
# do this before QtGui is imported elsewhere
QtGui.qApp = MyApplication()
```

You can then provide accessor methods that will allow you to navigate your widget hierarchy from the top-down:

```
       button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: QtGui.qApp.tabManager().setCurrentIndex(2))
```

(NB: explicitly setting `qApp` isn't optional - you won't be able to access any attributes of your subclass without doing that).

Comment: I want to reuse the WidgetC in other tab or even other applications. So if the WidgetC don't need to know the parents but just emit its signal would be better.

Comment: There's no such thing as generic signals in Qt. You are always connecting two specific objects, even if they are not in a parent/child relationship. But the fact of the matter is, in your example, the `WidgetC` instances **do** know about their parents, because they are referencing `show_another_tab`. They also know about the other tabs, because they refer to their specific indexes. Really, the `WidgetA` class should be responsible for connecting the signals, and the `WidgetB` and `WidgetC` classes should have generic interfaces (i.e. like a standard item model and its standard items).

Comment: Sorry I didn't write the example more clearly. The `WidgetC` is not referenceing `show_another_tab`, the `show_another_tab` is a signal of itself. The `WidgetA` happens to have a `show_another_tab` just become I want to handle the `show_another_tab` signal in a function with the same name. I noticed there is a event system besides signal system in qt. Can I create a custom event and handle this event in `WidgetA` by eventFilter? I'm searching for this approach. Thank you.

Comment: @kkpattern. Sorry, it is clear - I just missed that detail. it doesn't really change my previous comment, though. The `WidgetC` class knows that it is part of a tab inside a tab-widget, and it also has knowledge about the other tabs (i.e. their specific indexes). It may be that your example is unrealistic, but this just seems backwards to me. The `WidgetA` class should be managing the tabs, rather than widgets inside the tabs trying to control the tab-manager from the bottom-up.

Comment: You can take `WidgetC` as a hotlink for user to jump to a specific tab. Since `WidgetC` can be put anywhere(inside `WidgetB`, inside `WidgetD`...), it won't know the length of the parent chain to `WidgetA`. I think put `WidgetA` in a global variable would be the better way. Through in this way, is hard to reuse the `WidgetC` in other applications.